# Studies about the impact of testing (especially model based testing)

Tags: automated-testing

I'm looking for some studies, papers, statistics, ... about the (hopefully positive) impact of software testing in IT projects, especially the use of [model based testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-based_testing) (MBT).

I've read about the chaos report published by the standish group but I'm not sure whether its really sound?!

Comment: Do you mean the chaos report of the Standish group? http://www.projectsmart.co.uk/docs/chaos-report.pdf

Comment: Yes exactly. I edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

A study from the early 90's about software ? I can hardly call it relevant to today's software industry.
The change in technology is far more than just a gradual increase in scale, it requires totally different approach.
Terms like continuous delivery, SaaS, testing in production or A/B testing are related to much more than another suite of functional or load tests they require a totally different approach to development and even the product and customers themselves.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for recent studies (in the context of MBT if possible). The chaos report was just an example of what I've already found.

Comment: Understood, when I was involved in an initiative to encourage academic studies and involvement in software testing and the software testing industry I looked for similar studies but found none.
The studies I saw were about methods e.g. applying statistical method to software testing or deep investigation of a specific problem e.g. influence of mobile file systems on user experience